# Execute system command with groovy

Tags: javascript, groovy

I have a sample `js` script, which provides me to see files located in the server `myHost`, so it works perfectly:

```
var exec = require('ssh-exec')
var v_host = 'myHost'
exec('ls -lh', {
    user: 'username',
    host: v_host,
    password: 'password'
}).pipe(process.stdout , function (err, data) {
    if ( err ) { console.log(v_host); console.log(err); }
    console.log(data)
})
```

Now I want to set `host` when I'm trying to execute `system commands` from groovy. Here is my sample groovy script, but this works on the local system, actually I see files which is located on my local server:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ls -l")
p.waitFor();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

StringBuilder execSb = new StringBuilder();
String line = "";           
while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
    execSb.append(line + "\n");
}
```

Can I give `host` to `exec` method likes `js script`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssh-exec executes remote system command

one of the variants: download jschXX.jar library and put it into groovy/lib directory

then you should be able to use following groovy code:

```
def ant = new AntBuilder()
ant.sshexec{
    host:           "somehost", 
    username:       "dude",
    password:       "yo",
    command:        "touch somefile",
    outputproperty: "ssh_stdout"
}
println ant.ssh_stdout
```

can't try the code right now.

parameters rererence for `ant.sshexec` command: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshexec.html